# SQL Server is not reading environment variable

Tags: sql-server, xp-cmdshell

I want to create a CLR assembly, and here's my code:

```
use [master]
go

exec sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
go

reconfigure
go

exec sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
go

reconfigure
go

execute sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1
go

reconfigure
go

execute sp_configure 'clr strict security', 0
go

reconfigure
go

declare @path varchar(256) = '';
declare @table table
(
    Value varchar(256)
)
insert into @table execute xp_cmdshell 'echo %CompanyProjectsRoot%'
set @path = 
(
    select top 1 Value 
    from @table
)
set @path = @path + '\Framework\Packages\Company.ClrIntegration.dll'
create assembly CompanyClrIntegration from @path
go
```

And I receive this error:

> CREATE ASSEMBLY failed because it could not read from the physical file '%CompanyProjectsRoot%\Framework\Packages\Company.ClrIntegration.dll': 50(The request is not supported.).

But if I change the path to absolute path `C:\Copmany\Framework\Packages\Company.ClrIntegration.dll` it works.

And I know that `%CompanyProjectsRoot%` is already defined for the entire machine using this command:

```
setx CompanyProjectsRoot C:\Company /m
```

And I have also restarted SQL Server Management Studio. But still it does not expand environment variable.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you restart SQL Server since you configured the variable? SSMS is irrelevant, it is just a client tool. Also note that the variable need to be on the server machine, not the client.

Comment: @Ah cloud, what is output of this table `@table`?

Comment: @TiborKaraszi, such a good advice. Yep, it worked. Please send your comment as an answer, so that I can accepts it.

Comment: @AH Cloud, I'm glad it helped!

Comment: You'd be better defining it as a `PATH` environment variable, then you wouldn't need to mess around with `xp_cmdshell` at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you restart the SQL Server service since you configured the environment variable? I believe that environment variables for MSSQL are read at start-up time for the database engine.

Also, SSMS is irrelevant, it is just a client tool. And, note that the variable need to be on the server machine, not the client.